# Problem with saving faviorites items to room database, saved dublicate items and unable to check if it's saved too

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

While I updating some parts of my app, I think I doing some mistake or something is missing that causes this problem, the problem is happening when I tried to save any item to the favorites table, and after I saved it I open the same item (fragment details again) I should see the favorite icon **(heart icon)** filled with red color which means the item is already saved and If I click on it again it should be removed and so on...

now I see the item saved but when I click the back button and click on the item again the icon doesn't change and that's meaning the user can save it again (which causes duplicated items in recyclerView)

### Problem in GIF

[image]

here's my code

**FavoritesEntity class**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "favorites")
data class FavoritesEntity(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int, val item: Item) : Parcelable
```

**Database class**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Item::class, FavoritesEntity::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
) //@TypeConverters(Converters.class)

//@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
//@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@TypeConverters(ItemTypeConverter::class)
abstract class ItemsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    //    private static ItemsDatabase INSTANCE;
    abstract val itemDAO: ItemDAO
    
    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ItemsDatabase? = null


        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): ItemsDatabase {


            if (INSTANCE == null) {

                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ItemsDatabase::class.java,
                    "items_database"
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                return INSTANCE!!
            }
            return INSTANCE as ItemsDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemDAO**

```
@Dao
interface ItemDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertItem(item: Item)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertFavorites(favoritesEntity: FavoritesEntity)

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM FAVORITES")
    val getAllFavorites: Flow<List<FavoritesEntity>>

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteFavorite(favoritesEntity: FavoritesEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM FAVORITES")
    suspend fun deleteAllFavorites()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table order by datetime(published) DESC")
    fun getAlItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE title like '%' || :keyword || '%' ")
    suspend fun getItemsBySearch(keyword: String?): List<Item>
}
```

**DetailsViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepository: MainRepository,
    private val dataStoreRepository: DataStoreRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _favoritesPostList = MutableLiveData<List<FavoritesEntity>>()
    val favoritesPostList: LiveData<List<FavoritesEntity>> get() = _favoritesPostList


    fun getFavoritePosts() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainRepository.localDataSource.getAllFavorites().collect {
                _favoritesPostList.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    val readRecyclerViewPortraitLayout =
        dataStoreRepository.readRecyclerViewPortraitLayout.asLiveData()
    val readRecyclerViewLandscapeLayout =
        dataStoreRepository.readRecyclerViewLandscpaeLayout.asLiveData()

    fun saveRecyclerViewPortraitLayout(layout: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreRepository.saveRecyclerViewPortraitLayout(layout)
        }
    }

    fun saveRecyclerViewLandscapeLayout(layout: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreRepository.saveRecyclerViewLandscapeLayout(layout)
        }
    }

    fun insertFavorites(favoritesEntity: FavoritesEntity) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            mainRepository.localDataSource.insertFavorites(favoritesEntity)
        }
    }

    fun deleteFavoritePost(favoritesEntity: FavoritesEntity) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mainRepository.localDataSource.deleteFavorite(favoritesEntity)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllFavorites() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mainRepository.localDataSource.deleteAllFavorites()
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailsActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var _binding: ActivityDetailsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var url: String? = null
    private var title: String? = null
    private var content: String? = null
    private var youtubeThumbnailImageSrc: String? = null
    private var youTubeLink: String? = null
    private var youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility: Int? = null

    private var html: Spannable? = null

    private val detailsViewModel: DetailsViewModel by viewModels()

    private var postItem: Item? = null

    private var postFavoritesSaved = false
    private var postFavoritesSavedId = 0
    private var menuItem: MenuItem? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = ActivityDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Log.d(
            TAG,
            "onCreate checkSavedFavoritesItems: $postFavoritesSavedId"
        )


        postItem = if (intent.extras!!.containsKey("postItem")) {
            intent.getParcelableExtra("postItem")!!
        } else {
            val favoriteItem: FavoritesEntity = intent.getParcelableExtra("favoriteItem")!!
            favoriteItem.item
        }
  
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        changeMenuItemIcon(menuItem, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(null)
        adRequest = null
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun changeMenuItemIcon(menuItem: MenuItem?, icFavoriteBorder: Int) {
        menuItem?.setIcon(icFavoriteBorder)
    }

        private fun checkSavedFavoritesItems(menuItem: MenuItem?) {
        detailsViewModel.favoritesPostList.observe(this) { favoritesEntity ->
            try {
                
                favoritesEntity.forEach {
                    if (it.item.id == postItem?.id) {
                        changeMenuItemIcon(menuItem, R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                        postFavoritesSavedId = it.id
                        Log.d(TAG, "checkSavedFavoritesItems: $postFavoritesSavedId")
                        postFavoritesSaved = true
                    }
                }
                
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "checkSavedFavoritesItems: " + exception.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.details_menu, menu)
        menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_to_favorites)
        checkSavedFavoritesItems(menuItem)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when {
            menuItem.itemId == R.id.action_add_to_favorites && !postFavoritesSaved -> {
                saveTogFavorites(menuItem)
            }
            menuItem.itemId == R.id.action_add_to_favorites && postFavoritesSaved -> {
                removePostFromFavorites(menuItem)
            }

            menuItem.itemId == android.R.id.home -> this.finish()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
    }


    private fun saveTogFavorites(menuItem: MenuItem) {
        val favoritesEntity = postItem?.let {
            FavoritesEntity(0, it)
        }
        if (favoritesEntity != null) {
            detailsViewModel.insertFavorites(favoritesEntity)
        }
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
        Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Saved", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        postFavoritesSaved = true
    }

    private fun removePostFromFavorites(menuItem: MenuItem) {
        val favoritesEntity = postItem?.let { FavoritesEntity(postFavoritesSavedId, it) }
        Log.d(
            TAG, "checkSavedFavoritesItems: $postFavoritesSavedId"
        )
        if (favoritesEntity != null) {
            detailsViewModel.deleteFavoritePost(favoritesEntity)
        }
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)
        Snackbar.make(
            binding.root,
            "Post deleted from favorites", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        postFavoritesSaved = false
    }
```

I tried to check for `postFavoritesSavedId` in the log and I got 0 eachtime, so I tried to change it to get the item itself long ID instead favoritesEntity incremental id but doesn't work

Comment: I see that the `id` for the `FavoritesEntity` is `autoGenerate = true` which could be the issue here. So every time you add the item, a `new` id is generated causing duplicates.

Comment: changed `id` to `autoGenerate = false` it's cause the new saved item replaced the new one

Comment: You need to provide a set of `Id`s that would not change, you can use the `url.hashCode` as `Id` since every `Url` would be different for each entity.

Comment: @darshan the problem is solved, I just forgot to call method that gets favorites items before observing, thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this method `checkSavedFavoritesItems` you observsed in `favoritesEntity` but you forgot to call `getFavoritePosts` method because of that this problem happend